# Oracle sql search rows containing one or more keyword and sum by its keyword

Tags: oracle, subquery

I want to calculate sum by a different text, but the subquery keeps returning multiple rows, instead of a single row.
I was doing like this:

```
select sub.aid, 
sum (case when sub.text like '%abc' then sub.value end),
sum (case when sub.text like '%def' then sub.value end), ...

from (
   select a.aid, a.value, a.text
   from atable a, btable b
   where a.aid = b.bid and 
       a.aid = any (select aid
                 from atable
                 where text like '%abc' or text like '%def' or text like '%ghi' ....
                 group by aid
                 having count(*) >=1)
) sub
group by sub.aid
```

I am getting ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row error. 
I don't know what the problem is. How do I get the query work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'in' instead of '=any' also does not work.

Comment: Is there any other subquery in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to break it down, starting from the innermost query and climb up to the outermost query.

In your innermost query, the `having` part is redundant. You will not get any rows if the `count(*)` is 0 even without it. Having said that, there is no need for `group by` here, instead you can simply select `distinct`:

```
select distinct aid
from atable
where text like '%abc' or text like '%def' or text like '%ghi' ....
```

For the second query:

- Use explicit joins. the join style you used is out of date by more than 20 years.
- I'm not an oracle guy myself but I did some digging, it turns out that `any` is probably not what you are looking for, and you should probably use `in` instead.
- It's not very clear why you use an inner join with `btable`, unless it's to make sure that any result you get exists in both tables. To me it looks like you do a self join and `btable` is a typo and should have been `atable`. However, this makes even less sense.

After fixing the first 2 points we get this query:

```
select a.aid, a.value, a.text
from atable a 
inner join btable b on(a.aid = b.bid)
where a.aid in (
                select distinct aid
                from atable
                where text like '%abc' or text like '%def' or text like '%ghi' ....
               )
```

Now as I hope you can see, this is basically the same is this:

```
select a.aid, a.value, a.text
from atable a 
inner join btable b on(a.aid = b.bid)
where a.text like '%abc' or a.text like '%def' or a.text like '%ghi' ....
```

So there is really no need for the innermost query.

Moving on to your outermost query:
Again, there is something strange hare. I don't see the reason to have one more query wrapping the middle query just for the `group by`. This query should probably get you your excepted results:

```
select a.aid, 
       sum (case when a.text like '%abc' then a.value end),
       sum (case when a.text like '%def' then a.value end), ...
from atable a 
inner join btable b on(a.aid = b.bid)
where a.text like '%abc' or a.text like '%def' or a.text like '%ghi' ....
group by a.aid
```